# Entropy change during adiabatic expansion of ideal gas

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, physical-chemistry, adiabatic

I was told that the entropy change is $0$ during adiabatic expansion. However, according to $\mathrm dS=\frac{C}{T}\,\mathrm dT$, $\delta S$ is not zero because temperature is not constant during adiabatic process. What is wrong in my derivation?

Comment: Hi Irene and welcome to the Physics SE. Did you mean a *reversible* adiabatic expansion? Note that $dS = dq/T$ applies only to a reversible process. For an irreversible process it's $dS \ge dq/T$.

Comment: @ John Rennie Yes I meant reversible adiabatic expansion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was told that the entropy change is 0 during [reversible] adiabatic expansion.

I believe you misheard, or the person was mistaken. Entropy *production* or generation is zero for a reversible process. Entropy can certainly change upon expansion, as the number and distribution of microstates can vary.

The important aspect of a reversible process is that any gain (loss) in system entropy require a loss (gain) in the entropy of the rest of the universe. Expansion, for example, leaves more positional options for the system but fewer for the matter in the rest of the universe.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. Did you mean that the entropy of the system and the environment both change, but they add up to zero? If so, how does the entropy of the environment change? Since there is no heat transfer between the system and the environment, it seems like there's no way for the entropy of the environment to change.

Comment: Yes. By expanding your system into the surrounding environment, you reduced the positional options of the matter in the rest of the universe.

Answer (score 0):

Who told you that, and what was the context? As it it, it's incorrect.

Any entropic variation for a system is the sum of two terms:
$$dS=\delta S_e+\delta S_c$$
with $\delta S_e$ standing for variation due to thermal exchange with the environment:
$$\delta S_e=\frac{\delta Q}{T_\text{ext}}$$
and $\delta S_c$ related to the second law of thermodynamics (zero for a reversible process, positive otherwise).

Back to your question, if the process is adiabatic, $\delta Q=0$ so $\delta S_e$ is zero but that leaves $\delta S_c$ free to be non zero. So entropy has no reason to be constant... except for a reversible process, which you didn't specify.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I meant reversible adiabatic process.

Answer (score 0):

Your equation is incorrect if the pressure and volume change, as in an expansion.  Under these circumstances, $$dS=C_v\frac{dT}{T}+R\frac{dV}{V}=C_p\frac{dT}{T}-R\frac{dP}{P}$$